# How to retrieve data from another Excel column into a PowerShell array?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'd like to create an array, which contains an Excel column. Where the current cell is empty, it has to retrieve the data from the other column.

Now my code looks like:

```
$rowMax=($OpenedWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows).count

$arrTeilenummer=@() 
$arrItem=@()

$i = 2

Do { 
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($arrTeilenummer)){
    $arrTeilenummer=$arrItem}

        elseif ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($arrItem)){
        $arrItem=$arrTeilenummer}

    $arrTeilenummer += $OpenedWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, 4).value() 
    $arrItem += $OpenedWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, 8).value()

    $i++ 
} 

While ($i -le $rowMax)
```

And this code simply skip the empty cells, like normal case.

Comment: Please show a representative sample of your code. What are `$arrTeilenummer` and `$arrItem`?

Comment: Edited. I hope everything is here already.:)